# Convert string decimal numbers in column to float in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this (with many more columns):

```
      FLAG__DC SEXECOND CRM_TAUX
0            N        M      0,9
1            N        M      0,9
2            N        M      1,2
3            O        M        1
4            N        M        1
5            N        M      0,9
6            O        M        1
7            N        M      0,9
```

I want to convert the column `CRM_TAUX` to Float... Please help!

I have tried this but doesn't work:

```
df['CRM_TAUX'] = df.CRM_TAUX.replace(',','.')
df['CRM_TAUX'] = df.CRM_TAUX.apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

This is the error I get (and many more):

```
Unable to parse string "1,2" at position 0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please show us the error you are getting?

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.replace`

```
df.CRM_TAUX.str.replace(',' , '.')

Out[2246]:
0    0.9
1    0.9
2    1.2
3      1
4      1
5    0.9
6      1
7    0.9
Name: CRM_TAUX, dtype: object
```

---

Next, call `pd.to_numeric`  on it should work

```
s = df.CRM_TAUX.str.replace(',' , '.')
df['CRM_TAUX'] = pd.to_numeric(s)


Out[2250]:
  FLAG__DC SEXECOND  CRM_TAUX
0        N        M       0.9
1        N        M       0.9
2        N        M       1.2
3        O        M       1.0
4        N        M       1.0
5        N        M       0.9
6        O        M       1.0
7        N        M       0.9
```

Comment: Works like a charm, also added `errors='coerce'` in `pd.to_numeric()` for extra perfection. Thanks!